# CriteriaBuilder returns nothing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I'm working on CriteriaBuilder. If the record exists, it will correctly return a value.
But I need the query to return a value, e.g. an empty string or "," if the record is not found.
Currently, if it doesn't find the record, it returns nothing. It just jumps.

> ```
>     CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
>     CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
>     Root<Stock> stock = criteriaQuery.from(Stock.class);
>     criteriaQuery.select(stock.get(storage))
>         .where(stock.get(ITEM_NR).in(eans));
>     return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
> ```

So now
is 1,2,4
instead r 1,2,,4

If 3 doesn't exist.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by using IFNULL:

```
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.selectCase().when(criteriaBuilder.isNull(stock.get(storage),-1).otherwise(stock.get(storage)))
```

I didn't test this code but I think this is the right track to go with. Please try and give us an update on the results

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  This isn't about returning `null` or an empty list, but about having some weird `0` entries in the result list for the not fitting IDs. eG if he has IDS 1,2,3,4 and 5 in the Database and his query would only match the ID 3 he wants a List with `[0, 0, 3, 0, 0]` as a result.  Now don't ask me what the point of those `0` in the result list is....that is something probably only OP knows.

Comment: Yes exactly. It doesn't have to be zero. Ideally, an empty string should replace the record that was not found.

Comment: My bad., you're right. I misunderstood. I'll try to help you with that.

Comment: I don't know how to change my query. If you help, it will be great.

Comment: Please note that you can't add an empty String in a list of Long. I'm setting the default value as -1

Comment: Unfortunately, but in place stock.get(storage),-1 I get: Expected 1 arguments but found 2

Comment: It could be a list of strings. It doesn't have to be list of Long.

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is normal (expected) behaviour. You are requesting all entries that match another set (IN), then the result will only contain information about those entries, and NOT any information about entries that did not match your cirteria.

If you want to achieve this behaviour, you will have to map all entries using a conditional mapping.

This can be done a couple of ways:

- create a complex criteria query that will project the result of the `storage` field conditionally on existence in the `earns` set...
- create a second criteria query that returns only those stock's that are NOT in the `earns` set and handle those separately
- write the query as a (non criteria) JPA query
- get all `Stock` items and loop/stream and map them in Java code to determine if they are part of the `earns` set

I think the real question to me is; what is the context of the result that you return from the query. It seems that there is only information about `storage` without the context of the `Stock` that it belongs to...  But that is for you to determine...